# linking error with one function only LNK 2019

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I have following class inside dll

```
header

class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass
{
public:
bool fun1(const CString& csFilename, int& nFileID );
bool fun2(int nFileID, int nImageNum, int nStartIndex);
};

cpp

bool MyClass::fun1(const CString& csFilename, int& nFileID )
{
}

bool Myclass::fun2(int nFileID, int nImageNum, int nStartIndex)
{
}

main

void main()
{
MyClass *p = new MyClass;
p->fun1(...); //if I comment this code compiles and builds
p->fun2(...); //this is ok
}
```

I am getting error  LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall...
only for fun1 not for fun2 even both are in same class why ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the actual function calls and the actual error text.

Comment: sorry can not provide actual code still thanks for hint I will check in this direction.

Comment: What do you mean you can't provide the actual code? All you need to do is show how you call `fun1`, and paste the compiler output. I highly doubt either contain important trade secrets.

Comment: thanks for your hint it works the problem is CString I replaced it with std::string, I will answer once I get more technical details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is wrong here as it works after I replace CString with std string but I am not able to reproduce same error in another small example.
@ admin I think this thread should be deleted as i am not able to reproduce it.